# PHP resized thumbnail is black?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the script from [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) and modifying the create_scaled_image function to work in conjunction with my DB.  Looks like the image is getting re-sized but the rsized image is completely black. Any idea what would cause this?

Here are my modifications to the script:

```
private function create_scaled_image($file_name, $options) {

    list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_name);

    error_log("Width: $img_width");
    error_log("Height: $img_height");

    if (!$img_width || !$img_height) {
        return false;
    }
    $scale = min(
        $options['max_width'] / $img_width,
        $options['max_height'] / $img_height
    );

    error_log("SCALE: $scale");
    if ($scale > 1) {
        $scale = 1;
    }
    $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
    $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
    $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif($file_name);
            break;
        case 'png':
            @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
            @imagealphablending($new_img, false);
            @imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
            $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_name);
            break;
        default:
            $src_img = $image_method = null;
    }

    @imagecopyresampled(
        $new_img,
        $src_img,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $new_width,
        $new_height,
        $img_width,
        $img_height
    ); 

    // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
    @imagedestroy($src_img);

    return $new_img;
}
```

My call to the function looks like this:

```
        $options['max_width'] = 80;
        $options['max_height'] = 80;

        $thumb_source = $this->create_scaled_image($uploaded_file, $options);

        ob_start(); // Start capturing stdout.
        imagejpeg($thumb_source); // As though output to browser.
        $thumb_bin = mysql_real_escape_string(ob_get_contents()); // the raw jpeg image data.
        ob_end_clean(); // Dump the stdout so it does not screw other output.

        // Code to insert data into my DB here
```

Comment: Remove the @'s in the code and look for the errors (if any).

Comment: What are the @'s doing in front of the functions names? I was able to track the error down after I removed them...

Comment: They supress any error occuring while using the function behind @.

Comment: good to know...I learn something every day :)  Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind submitting that as your answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the @'s in the code and look for the errors (if any). @ supress any error occuring while using the function behind.